# Equation for testing if a point is inside a circle

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry

If you have  a circle with center `(center_x, center_y)` and radius `radius`, how do you test if a given point with coordinates `(x, y)` is inside the circle?

Comment: This question is really language agnostic, I am using the same formula  in java, So re-tagging.

Comment: It seems that your assuming positive coordinates only. The solutions below don't work with signed coordinates.

Comment: Most solutions below *do* work with positive and negative coordinates.  Just correcting that tidbit for future viewers of this question.

Answer (score 615):

In general, `x` and `y` must satisfy `(x - center_x)² + (y - center_y)² < radius²`.

Please note that points that satisfy the above equation with `<` replaced by `==` are considered the points *on* the circle, and the points that satisfy the above equation with `<` replaced by `>` are considered the *outside* the circle.

Comment: It may help some less math minded folks to see the square root operation used to measure distance compared against the radius.  I realize that's not optimal, but as your answer is formatted more like an equation than code perhaps it makes more sense?  Just a suggestion.

Comment: This is the most comprehensible explanation provided in just a simple sentence and a immediately useable equation. Well done.

Comment: this is great wish i would of found this resource quicker. Where does the value x come from?

Comment: @DevinTripp 'x' is the x coordinate of the point being tested.

Comment: This may be obvious, but it should be stated that `<=` will find points inside the circle or on its edge.

Comment: @makinbacon I found it obvious, but the fact that it wasn't mentioned made me wonder if there was something I wasn't thinking of.

Comment: Why is there no square root?

Answer (score 169):

Mathematically, Pythagoras is probably a simple method as many have already mentioned.

```
(x-center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2
```

Computationally, there are quicker ways. Define:

```
dx = abs(x-center_x)
dy = abs(y-center_y)
R = radius
```

**If a point is more likely to be *outside* this circle** then imagine a square drawn around it such that it's sides are tangents to this circle:

```
if dx>R then 
    return false.
if dy>R then 
    return false.
```

Now imagine a square diamond drawn inside this circle such that it's vertices touch this circle:

```
if dx + dy <= R then 
    return true.
```

Now we have covered most of our space and only a small area of this circle remains in between our square and diamond to be tested. Here we revert to Pythagoras as above.

```
if dx^2 + dy^2 <= R^2 then 
    return true
else 
    return false.
```

**If a point is more likely to be *inside* this circle** then reverse order of first 3 steps:

```
if dx + dy <= R then 
    return true.
if dx > R then 
    return false.
if dy > R 
    then return false.
if dx^2 + dy^2 <= R^2 then 
    return true
else
    return false.
```

---

Alternate methods imagine a square inside this circle instead of a diamond but this requires slightly more tests and calculations with no computational advantage (inner square and diamonds have identical areas):

```
k = R/sqrt(2)
if dx <= k and dy <= k then 
    return true.
```

Update:

For those interested in performance I implemented this method in c, and compiled with -O3.

I obtained execution times by `time ./a.out`

I implemented this method, a normal method and a dummy method to determine timing overhead.

`Normal: 21.3s
This: 19.1s
Overhead: 16.5s`

So, it seems this method is more efficient in this implementation.

```c
// compile gcc -O3 <filename>.c
// run: time ./a.out

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE  (0==0)
#define FALSE (0==1)

#define ABS(x) (((x)<0)?(0-(x)):(x))

int xo, yo, R;

int inline inCircle( int x, int y ){  // 19.1, 19.1, 19.1
  int dx = ABS(x-xo);
  if (    dx >  R ) return FALSE;
  int dy = ABS(y-yo);
  if (    dy >  R ) return FALSE;
  if ( dx+dy <= R ) return TRUE;
  return ( dx*dx + dy*dy <= R*R );
}

int inline inCircleN( int x, int y ){  // 21.3, 21.1, 21.5
  int dx = ABS(x-xo);
  int dy = ABS(y-yo);
  return ( dx*dx + dy*dy <= R*R );
}

int inline dummy( int x, int y ){  // 16.6, 16.5, 16.4
  int dx = ABS(x-xo);
  int dy = ABS(y-yo);
  return FALSE;
}

#define N 1000000000

int main(){
  int x, y;
  xo = rand()%1000; yo = rand()%1000; R = 1;
  int n = 0;
  int c;
  for (c=0; c<N; c++){
    x = rand()%1000; y = rand()%1000;
//    if ( inCircle(x,y)  ){
    if ( inCircleN(x,y) ){
//    if ( dummy(x,y) ){
      n++;
    }
  }
  printf( "%d of %d inside circle\n", n, N);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know if you have profiled these optimizations? My gut feeling is that multiple conditionals would be slower than some math and one conditional, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @yoyo, I have preformed no profiling - this question is about a method for any programming language. If someone thinks this might improve performance in their application then they should, as you suggest, demonstrate it is faster in normal scenarios.

Comment: In function `inCircleN` you're using unnecessary ABS. Probably without ABS difference between `inCircle` and `inCircleN` would be smaller.

Comment: @tzaloga is right... Squared values are always positive.

Comment: Removing ABS does improve inCircleN performance but not enough. However, my method was biased towards points more likely outside of circle since R=1. With random radius [0..499], about 25% points were inside circle and inCircleN is faster.

Comment: Small optimization: when you need to check multiple points in a certain circle of radius r, r*r is constant and can be calculated outside the loop.

Answer (score 87):

You can use Pythagoras to measure the distance between your point and the centre and see if it's lower than the radius:

```
def in_circle(center_x, center_y, radius, x, y):
    dist = math.sqrt((center_x - x) ** 2 + (center_y - y) ** 2)
    return dist <= radius
```

**EDIT** (hat tip to Paul)

In practice, squaring is often much cheaper than taking the square root and since we're only interested in an ordering, we can of course forego taking the square root:

```
def in_circle(center_x, center_y, radius, x, y):
    square_dist = (center_x - x) ** 2 + (center_y - y) ** 2
    return square_dist <= radius ** 2
```

Also, Jason noted that `<=` should be replaced by `<` and depending on usage this may actually make sense <del>even though I believe that it's not true in the strict mathematical sense</del>. *I stand corrected.*

Comment: Replace dist <= radius by dist < radius to test for the point being inside the circle.

Comment: sqrt is expensive.  Avoid it if possible - compare the x^2+y^y to r^2.

Comment: Jason: our definitions may disagree but for me, a point that is *on* the circle's circumference is most emphatically also *in* the circle and I am pretty sure that mine is in agreement with the formal, mathematical definition.

Comment: @Paul: That's correct in practice but I wanted to illustrate Pythagoras. Other answers have included this optimization.

Comment: The formal mathematical definition of the interior of a circle is that which I gave in my post. From Wikipedia: In general, the interior of something refers to the space or part inside of it, excluding any kind of wall or boundary around its outside. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)

Comment: In pascal, delphi and FPC, both power, and sqrt is to _expensive_, and there's no power-operator EG: `**` or `^`. The fastest way to do it when you just need x^2 or x^3 is to do it "manually": `x*x`.

Comment: @JHolta, why do you think that Delphi's (or FPC's on x86) `Sqr` power function is expensive ? `Sqrt` might be, but that's what Konrad mentioned in his update suggested by Paul's comment...

Comment: @TLama i only said that `power`, and `Sqrt` is expensive. I did not mention `Sqr` at all. But I do believe that there is some overhead if you use `Sqr`, maybe the compiler is smart and solves it (replaces it with x*x to remove the functioncall).

Comment: @JHolta, there is no overhead; both `Sqr` and `x*x` results to `imul` instruction ;-)

Answer (score 40):

```
boolean isInRectangle(double centerX, double centerY, double radius, 
    double x, double y)
{
        return x >= centerX - radius && x <= centerX + radius && 
            y >= centerY - radius && y <= centerY + radius;
}    

//test if coordinate (x, y) is within a radius from coordinate (center_x, center_y)
public boolean isPointInCircle(double centerX, double centerY, 
    double radius, double x, double y)
{
    if(isInRectangle(centerX, centerY, radius, x, y))
    {
        double dx = centerX - x;
        double dy = centerY - y;
        dx *= dx;
        dy *= dy;
        double distanceSquared = dx + dy;
        double radiusSquared = radius * radius;
        return distanceSquared <= radiusSquared;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is more efficient, and readable. It avoids the costly square root operation.  I also added a check to determine if the point is within the bounding rectangle of the circle.

The rectangle check is unnecessary except with many points or many circles.  If most points are inside circles, the bounding rectangle check will actually make things slower!

As always, be sure to consider your use case.

Answer (score 20):

You should check whether the distance from the center of the circle to the point is smaller than the radius

using Python

```py
if (x-center_x)**2 + (y-center_y)**2 <= radius**2:
    # inside circle
```

Answer (score 15):

Find the distance between the center of the circle and the points given. If the distance between them is less than the radius then the point is inside the circle.
if the distance between them is equal to the radius of the circle then the point is on the circumference of the circle.
if the distance is greater than the radius then the point is outside the circle.

```
int d = r^2 - ((center_x-x)^2 + (center_y-y)^2);

if(d>0)
  print("inside");
else if(d==0)
  print("on the circumference");
else
  print("outside");
```

Answer (score 13):

Calculate the Distance

```
D = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(center_x - x, 2) + Math.Pow(center_y - y, 2))
return D <= radius
```

that's in C#...convert for use in python...

Comment: You can avoid two expensive Sqrt calls by comparing D-squared to radius-squared.

Answer (score 7):

As said above -- use Euclidean distance.

```
from math import hypot

def in_radius(c_x, c_y, r, x, y):
    return math.hypot(c_x-x, c_y-y) <= r
```

Answer (score 6):

The equation below is a expression that tests if a point is within a given circle where *xP* & *yP* are the coordinates of the point, *xC* & *yC* are the coordinates of the center of the circle and *R* is the radius of that given circle.

[image]

If the above expression is true then the point is within the circle.

Below is a sample implementation in C#:

```
    public static bool IsWithinCircle(PointF pC, Point pP, Single fRadius){
        return Distance(pC, pP) <= fRadius;
    }

    public static Single Distance(PointF p1, PointF p2){
        Single dX = p1.X - p2.X;
        Single dY = p1.Y - p2.Y;
        Single multi = dX * dX + dY * dY;
        Single dist = (Single)Math.Round((Single)Math.Sqrt(multi), 3);

        return (Single)dist;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

*This is the same solution as [mentioned by Jason Punyon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481151/4170242), but it contains a pseudo-code example and some more details. I saw his answer after writing this, but I didn't want to remove mine.*

I think the most easily understandable way is to first calculate the distance between the circle's center and the point. I would use this formula:

```
d = sqrt((circle_x - x)^2 + (circle_y - y)^2)
```

Then, simply compare the result of that formula, the distance (`d`), with the `radius`. If the distance (`d`) is less than or equal to the radius (`r`), the point is inside the circle (on the edge of the circle if `d` and `r` are equal).

Here is a pseudo-code example which can easily be converted to any programming language:

```
function is_in_circle(circle_x, circle_y, r, x, y)
{
    d = sqrt((circle_x - x)^2 + (circle_y - y)^2);
    return d <= r;
}
```

Where `circle_x` and `circle_y` is the center coordinates of the circle, `r` is the radius of the circle, and `x` and `y` is the coordinates of the point.

Answer (score 2):

My answer in C# as a complete cut & paste (not optimized) solution:

```
public static bool PointIsWithinCircle(double circleRadius, double circleCenterPointX, double circleCenterPointY, double pointToCheckX, double pointToCheckY)
{
    return (Math.Pow(pointToCheckX - circleCenterPointX, 2) + Math.Pow(pointToCheckY - circleCenterPointY, 2)) < (Math.Pow(circleRadius, 2));
}
```

Usage:

```
if (!PointIsWithinCircle(3, 3, 3, .5, .5)) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated previously, to show if the point is in the circle we can use the following

```
if ((x-center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2) {
    in.circle <- "True"
} else {
    in.circle <- "False"
}
```

To represent it graphically we can use:

```
plot(x, y, asp = 1, xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), col = ifelse((x-center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2,'green','red'))
draw.circle(0, 0, 1, nv = 1000, border = NULL, col = NA, lty = 1, lwd = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving into the world of 3D if you want to check if a 3D point is in a Unit Sphere you end up doing something similar. All that is needed to work in 2D is to use 2D vector operations.

```
    public static bool Intersects(Vector3 point, Vector3 center, float radius)
    {
        Vector3 displacementToCenter = point - center;

        float radiusSqr = radius * radius;

        bool intersects = displacementToCenter.magnitude < radiusSqr;

        return intersects;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 15, Accepted Answer written in Swift 5.5

```
func isInRectangle(center: CGPoint, radius: Double, point: CGPoint) -> Bool
{
    return point.x >= center.x - radius && point.x <= center.x + radius &&
    point.y >= center.y - radius && point.y <= center.y + radius
}

//test if coordinate (x, y) is within a radius from coordinate (center_x, center_y)
func isPointInCircle(center: CGPoint,
                     radius:Double, point: CGPoint) -> Bool
{
    if(isInRectangle(center: center, radius: radius, point: point))
    {
        var dx:Double = center.x - point.x
        var dy:Double = center.y - point.y
        dx *= dx
        dy *= dy
        let distanceSquared:Double = dx + dy
        let radiusSquared:Double = radius * radius
        return distanceSquared <= radiusSquared
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Why do you never do the sqrt (root) operation? Distance is Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

Answer (score 0):

I used the code below for beginners like me :).

public class incirkel {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x; 
    int y; 
    int middelx; 
    int middely; 
    int straal; {

// Adjust the coordinates of x and y 
x = -1;
y = -2;

// Adjust the coordinates of the circle
middelx = 9; 
middely = 9;
straal =  10;

{
    //When x,y is within the circle the message below will be printed
    if ((((middelx - x) * (middelx - x)) 
                    + ((middely - y) * (middely - y))) 
                    < (straal * straal)) {
                        System.out.println("coordinaten x,y vallen binnen cirkel");
    //When x,y is NOT within the circle the error message below will be printed
    } else {
        System.err.println("x,y coordinaten vallen helaas buiten de cirkel");
    } 
}



    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple java code for solving this problem:

and the math behind it : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198764/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle

```
boolean insideCircle(int[] point, int[] center, int radius) {
    return (float)Math.sqrt((int)Math.pow(point[0]-center[0],2)+(int)Math.pow(point[1]-center[1],2)) <= radius;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
if ((($x - $center_x) ** 2 + ($y - $center_y) ** 2) <=  $radius **2) {
    return true; // Inside
} else {
    return false; // Outside
}
```