# Point in circle algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you test if a point is inside a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/how-do-you-test-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle)

I need a way to determine if point P is inside circle C defined by  a center point and a radius.

Is there an algorithm for this?

Thanks

Comment: This is just a simple calculation.

Comment: Think about it like this: What is the [distance](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm) between C's center and P? Is it more than the radius?

Comment: this looks like a homework question?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/481144/546561

Comment: @tenfour A question being a blatant duplicate does.

Comment: @vzwick no, that warrants being closed. I was referring to the -4 votes before a duplicate had even been suggested.

Comment: @tenfour: The question shows no research effort. For example: a simple google for `find if a point is in a circle` yields answers pretty quickly.

Comment: @tenfour Also, a simple question !== a question demonstrating the lack of even the slightest amount of own thinking involved.

Comment: @Milo you've been a member for over two years and have amassed reputation in the top 5% of SO users. The down votes (to me) show the community expects better quality questions from you.

Comment: @amit To be fair, I see questions here all the time that show no research effort, have already been asked, and still get upvoted. This one, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792841/detect-if-user-clicks-inside-a-circle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, and the algorithm is quite simple. Just check if the distance from the point P to the center of the circle C is less than the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is:

The point is inside if the distance from the center to the point is less than the circle's radius.

As a silly optimization, if you need to do this a lot and the circles are more or less constant, compare to the square of the circle's radius to shave some time from the computation (since computing the distance involves computing the square root, which is more expensive than not doing so).

Answer (score 0):

Compute the distance between P and the center of the circle. If the distance is less than the radius, your point is inside the circle. Sounds easy!