# How to determine n locations inside a circle efficiently?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, google-maps, geolocation

Given this the scenario:

1. We have the order of 1,000,000 points around the world, specified by longitude and latitude;
2. We have a circle c based on a point pc (specified by longitude and latitude) and a radius rc
3. We want to efficiently determine which of the points are in the circle

I'm developing in C# and the locations stored in SQL server 2008.

So as I see it I have these 3 options:

1. Store the locations as longitude latitude floats and perform the calculations in C#.
2. Store the locations as geographical data types and perform the calculations in  SQL server 2008 like this:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE UserLocations
   [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   [CurrentLocation] [geography] NOT NULL

   ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetCurrentUsersInRange
   @userPoint geography, 
   @RangeInMeters int
   AS
   BEGIN

   select  UserId from UserLocations
   where @userPoint.STDistance(CurrentLocation) <= @RangeInMeters
   and UserId <> @userId

   END
   ```

   Disadvantages: problems using geographical data with LinqToSQL and LinqToEntities.

   Advantages: using dbms processing power over large data, and usage of the SQL Server spatial index.

3.Using some web service such as google's geolocation and calculation services.
So far I didn't find such web service.

**Which is the most efficient in your opinion?** Please justify your answer.

Thank you

Comment: [Equation for testing if a point is inside a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle)

Comment: @Magnus we're on the surface of a sphere here, not on a plane

Answer (score 1):

My naive approach would be to define a lat/long bounding box around the point pc and select from the database using `BETWEEN` on those box coordinates. Statistically around 79% of the points passing that test will be within the circle. A simple check in the code will weed out the ones outside the circle.

I say naive because I'm not familiar with the geometry capabilities of SQL Server.

Comment: Too Naive:
     1. 21% full scan is not efficient.
     2. Read about the SQL server 2008 Advantages I added in the question

Comment: I wouldn't dismiss @Mark Ransom's suggestion so readily. From experience, when dealing with simple point-distance queries as you are, you'll probably find a solution like Mark's will outperform the geography datatype, even with use of a spatial index. SQL Server's spatial datatypes really excel when you are dealing with complex geometries like LineStrings or Polygons, or when you want more complex topological tests like STContains(), STCrosses(), or STRelate(), but for straightforward point-to-point distance calculations you can get better performance using logic like Mark's.

Comment: @ozba, who said anything about a full scan? If the latitude and longitude in your database are indexed, the server can quickly find the intersection of the two ranges. The 21% figure only applies to the small subset of the DB returned by the query.

Comment: Yet again, the spatial indexing on the geographic data type give better performance.
see here: [SQL Server 2008 Spatial Indexing performance](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1976/sql-server-2008-spatial-index-performance)

Comment: @MarkRansom can you please give a code describing your "simple check" suggestion?
So we can discuss the efficiency of it.

Comment: @ozba - the article you linked to compares the performance *of a query using the geography datatype* with or without a spatial index. Clearly a spatial index is likely to improve performance in that case. What Mark is suggesting is to perform an initial filter of results using a BETWEEN predicate on two regular numeric columns - i.e. lat and long - using a nonclustered index. I.e. only use the spatial methods to perform the high accuracy check of the candidate points actually contained in the circle.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to using a geometric circle, you could SELECT all records within a certain distance (using STDistance) from the circle's center. But I don't know whether or not it would be faster or slower than the intersection solution you have listed.

If the 100,000 points are static, you could probably code something in C#, loading the list into memory and using bounding boxes to minimize the usage of the distance calculation (ie, Haversine). It would probably be faster because you're minimizing I/O.

However, if the points are not static (or you have them stored in SQL Server), I'd opt for using SQL Server, it's a lot easier. You'd definitely want to create the proper spatial indices. SQL Server's spacial indexing is pretty good, you may find that it can even out-perform the in-memory solution I listed above.

I haven't used LINQ for this type of work, I usually do it old-school with a SqlConnection and a Reader. I have read that LINQ mixed with Spatials is a problem.

I don't know about Google, do they have such a web service?

Comment: I would really appreciate If someone knows if Google have such a web service, cause I searched for it and didn't find something that answer the required scenario.

Comment: If the 100,000 points are yours (ie, not common landmarks, etc), then I doubt there is such a web service. This is more of a database task than a web service task.

Comment: If I could store them via the web service and query them afterwards,
Than it is suitable