# Detecting Objects in a radius

Tags: actionscript-3, object, distance, detect

I need to have a point check for objects around it based on distance, and it is not possible to determine what will be on the stage at any given time, so I cannot just trace everything that would near it.

How would I do this so it can also detect what the nearby object is, in addition to detecting the object?

Comment: Duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle

Answer (score 1):

Use Pythagorean, like in this example:

http://www.flepstudio.org/forum/tutorials/501-pythagorean-theorem-actionscript-3-0-a.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how many objects you'll be having on the screen at any one time, but how about cycling through all the children in the movieclip/stage and checking against each one. Something like-

```
function prox(limit:int):MovieClip{
    for(var i:int = 0; i<stage.numChildren;i++)
        if(Math.abs(MovieClip(stage.getChildAt(i)).x - point.x) < limit && 
           Math.abs(MovieClip(stage.getChildAt(i)).y - point.y) < limit){
            return MovieClip(stage.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could extend that to returning an array of MovieClips by just changing the return type

```
function prox(limit:int):Array{
```

adding an array var and changing the code inside the if to

```
array.push(MovieClip(stage.getChildAt(i));
```

and

```
return array;
```

Comment: That could be problematic, as there could be anywhere from 5-50 movie clips to be checked. Would that amount be an issue?

Comment: You might find that a larger amount of movieclips may slow it down, but I haven't tested the efficiency of this code. An alternative could be to have an invisible extension of the area around that point, and call a hit test function between that object and the array of objects.