# How can I make Turtle recognize a circle?

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a Python program with Turtle Graphics that draws 2 circles overlapping (like a Venn Diagram) within a rectangle, and plots random dots onto the Venn Diagram.

I have successfully done this, but now I want to make the program recognize if a point is in one of the circles or in the intersection of the Venn Diagram. I then want to change the color of the dots depending on which region they're in.

What I have done so far for the program is listed variables, defined the shapes and made a for loop to randomly generate points.

Comment: [*Venn* diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equation for testing if a point is inside a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ["What have you tried?"](http://whathaveyoutried.com) is a commonly cited article here. In short, when asking your question you should demonstrate that you've put effort into solving your problem. Ideally, you'll have some code to show, and specific problems with that code. You'll get a lot more positive responses if you try to adhere to that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`turtle` is just a graphics library- it doesn't keep track of the objects you've drawn on screen. So, to calculate if a given point is within one of your Venn diagram circles, you'll need to take the following steps:

1. Store each circle's coordinates when you call `circle()`
   (classes would be helpful, but chances are you haven't learned those yet)
2. Call a function to test if the point is in the stored circle coordinate space. This will be a purely mathematical operation on Cartesian coordinates. The link @Tim gave ([Equation for testing if a point is inside a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle)) will help you achieve this.

A little guidance on step 1:

When you draw a circle, you have its center (current turtle position), and a radius. From there, obtaining all points within that circle is just geometry (if you can't derive the formula, a quick search will help you out). I'd suggest that you make a function that draws a Venn diagram circle, and one that returns the points within a circle. Something like this:

```
def venn_circle(circle_color, circle_radius):
    """ Draws a colored circle, returns the points within. """
    turtle.color(circle_color)
    # <fill in: code to move, orient the turtle>
    center = turtle.position()
    # <fill in: code to draw the circle>
    return circle_coords(center, circle_radius)


def circle_coords(center, radius):
    """ Return the set of pixels within the circle. """
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

And one quick note- you should never do `from package import *`. It's okay in some cases, but will generally just lead to trouble. In my example code, I've assumed you've substituted this idiom for `import turtle`.

Comment: I had a look at the link and I now have a definition of pythagorus which tests how the points inside :                               def in_circle_a (center_x,center_y,circle_radius,circle_x,circle_y):
    dist**2_a = (center_x - circle_x) ** 2 + (center_y - circle_y) ** 2                                                                  
     
return dist**2_a < circle_radius ** 2                                                                    I just don't know how to store each circle's coordinates and I've tried putting in If statements in but I think I do need to figure out step 1.

Comment: Don't worry about it! In the future, I suggest you modify your question, and ping me (or whomever) with your changes. I've edited my answer to give you some help on how to achieve this. Let me know if you're still stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your help. To get what I wanted in the end (different colour in each sector) I used pythagorus and it even works in the intersection if you use an "and" statement for both Py formulas. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I had quite similar assignment, tried to solve it the simple way:

```
import tkinter
import random

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width = 300, height = 200, bg = "white")
canvas.pack()

n = 500

for i in range(n):
    x = random.randrange(0, 300)
    y = random.randrange(0, 200)
    bod = canvas.create_oval(x+3, y+3, x-3, y-3, fill = "black")
    if (x - 100)**2+(y - 100)**2 < 80**2:       #for dot in circle1 fill red
        canvas.itemconfig(bod, fill = "red")
    if (x - 180)**2+(y - 100)**2 < 90**2:       #for dot in circle2 fill blue
        canvas.itemconfig(bod, fill = "blue")
    if (x - 100)**2+(y - 100)**2 < 80**2 and (x - 180)**2+(y - 100)**2 < 90**2:
        canvas.itemconfig(bod, fill = "green")  #overlapping of circle1 and 2
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.