# Python: Checking If Coordinates Are Within Circle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make Turtle recognize a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049536/how-can-i-make-turtle-recognize-a-circle)

[image]I have a function that draws a few circles and I am going to place dots inside them. Depending if the dot falls within the circle, depends on wether the colour will change or not.

The biggest issue I am finding is how to check whether or not the dot is within the circle. Does anyone have any idea how to calculate coordinates within a circle or is their a method which can check coordinates against the circle?

Comment: is this a homework assignment? it looks very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049536/how-can-i-make-turtle-recognize-a-circle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Compute (Euclidean) distance to the circle's center,

   ```
   sqrt((x - center_x) ** 2 + (y - center_y) ** 2)
   ```
2. Check whether the result is less than the radius.

Comment: We tried this but it was too low on the Y access for some reason. I have attached a picture.

Comment: @MichaelH: this is *the* method. You must have had a bug in your code, maybe a round-off error.

Answer (score 15):

For a circle with center `(x,y)` and radius `r`, a point `(x1, y1)` is within the circle if

```
(x1-x)² + (y1-y)² <= r²
```

Comment: +1, this formulation is actually more elegant than mine and faster to compute since you can cache r².

Answer (score 1):

To check if a coordinate lies on a circle you can use the equation of the circle

```
a² + b² = r²
```

So to check if the point is inside the circle:

```
a² + b² <= r²
```