# How can I use Actor.hit for collision detection?

Tags: libgdx

How can I use Actor.hit in libgdx . I want to know when two Actors collide through animation, is the Actor.hit method what I would use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read the documentation: [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#hit-float-float-boolean-)

Hit is used for user input only, like touch and mouseevents. It is not how you detect collisions.

You would need to do that yourself with a Rectangle for example which you update like this:

```
private void updateBounds() {
    bounds.set(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

Then you can easily check for collisions/overlaps with other Actors.

Comment: @noone what if i have a single actor and it is circle , how can i detect touch only for the circular image.

Comment: then you need to override the hit method. How to check if the coordinate is in the circle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle