# creating random dots in java-fx

Tags: random, javafx, points

I want to create dots/ points in my java-fx application. But there are some conditions:

1)The dots should be random

2)The dots have to be bounded inside a circle ie all the dots must be inside a circle of given dimension

3)The concentration of dots must be far greater near the outer portion ie towards the boundary than anywhere else.

How do i do this ?

Comment: what have you tried? I love javafx, and would like to see this be a great Q&A for others to learn from...

Comment: You have any sample code? I dont feel like doing all this from 0.

Comment: Actually i was making a simple clock widget. I wanted to add a border to the clock with pattern ( border in the sense. like rim of wheel). So thought that placing random colored dots would be a good idea.

Comment: Ok..i think theres one way around the third condition..fill the entire circle with lots nd lots of dots and den draw another smaller circle on top of it. But how do i create dots bounded within a circle ?

Comment: Values thanks to the classic equation of a circle? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle

Comment: Yeah. Thnx a lot for the help.