# How do I check if I have just clicked on a certain object from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, cookies

Basicly I am creating a game that you click on falling objects, E.G cookies, and I need to know how to check and see if a certain cookie has been pressed so it can disappear but the problem is that its in an array.

Here is a bit of my code:
Input class...

```
public class Input implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(MainGame.CG)){
        if(MainGame.MG.inGame){
            //There is actually something else here but its classified (haha sorry about that)      
            if(e.getPoint().x > /*I NEED SOMETHING HERE*/){
                                    //tells you if the object has been pressed
                MainGame.CG.cookieClicked = true; //CG = ClickerGame
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

class with array...

```
public class ClickerGame extends JPanel{
    public int amount;
    public FallingObject[] fo = new FallingObject[120]; //THE ARRAY I'M HAVING TROUBLES WITH


     /*THE REST IS A SECRET (SORRY ABOUT THAT)*/
}
```

If you don't understand here is a picture to demonstrate what I need...
[image: And sorry about the terrible drawing]

Comment: Ok, the answer is ** A SECRET, SORRY ABOUT THAT **. In fact the missing code is the one related to your question, so post it (check how to do a http://sscce.org) or delete the question.

Comment: i reccomend a list. it's more dynamic than an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid having to check the coordinates of 120 different items on each click, make every element inside `FallingObject[]` aware of three things:

1. Its own area of influence (see sn00fy's answer)
2. The containing class (in this case probably `ClickerGame`
3. Its location in the array (an int)

To do this, you would need to change your `FallingObject` constructor to look something like this:

```
public void FallingObject(ClickerGame master, int index); //add whatever else is needed for Falling Object.
```

Then you could instantiate the array as follows.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
     fo[i] = new FallingObject(this, i ); //add anything else needed for the constructor
}
```

Then each FallingObject is responsible for its own state, and when clicked it is able to report back to the `ClickerGame` instance. All you need now is a method in ClickerGame which each `FallingObject` can call.

```
public void clickedObj(int index) {
FallingObject temp = null;
     if(index >= 0 && index < 120) {
          temp = fo[index];
          //Do stuff with temp :)
     }
}
```

To call this method from within `FallingObject` just reference the 'master' variable (which you should probably save as a global variable within the class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check every element in your `FallingObject[]` array if it intersects with the mouse pointer coordinates at the moment of the click.

You can implement a simple rectangle test or use a circle for each cookie as explained here:

[Equation for testing if a point is inside a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle)