# Placing mouse pointer within a given diameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an alert when the user moves his mouse pointer from coordinate `X=42, Y= 10` to the coordinates `X=40, Y=200`.

However, since these mouse points are very small, the user might not start and end at the exact coordinates. So what i want to do is to give a range where the user could start and end when the mouse is within a certain diameter.

How can i do this ?

[image]

Comment: I didn't get the scenario completely but sounds 'do'able with particular logical operators. In your case you are talking about going 2 pixels right and 190 pixels down. You may assign global variables and compare them later within the desired range.

Comment: Keep tracking window's mouse events and save the possitions needed.

Comment: Just test the distance to the point that you're looking for; and when it's below a certain value then your position is in the center?

Comment: There was an answer here a minute ago, i think that was something i was looking for. Please include it again.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle)?

Comment: @Illep I have to edit my answer, because I haven't read your question precisely. Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for?

```
$("body").mousemove(function(event) {
    var radius = 10, yourX = 40, yourY = 10;
    var xDimenion = yourX > event.pageX ? yourX - event.pageX : event.pageX - yourX;
    var yDimenion = yourY > event.pageY ? yourY - event.pageY : event.pageY - yourY;
    if(Math.sqrt(xDimenion * xDimenion + yDimenion * yDimenion ) < radius){
        //do some stuff
    }
});
```

I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Would Client-Side Image Maps work http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_image_links.htm (bottom) using an Image of a Dot and and "area shape" that is set to "circle"; that gives an exact radius (and the option to use poly) for a mouseover.