# MySQL Select N Closest Zip Codes For Each Row

Tags: mysql

I have a table full of zip codes. For example:

```
------------------------------
| zip | latitude | longitude |
------------------------------
|00001| 35.34543 | -76.34234 |
|00002| 43.23423 | -80.32423 |
...
|00008| 24.34543 | -20.53454 |
------------------------------
```

For each row I want to select the n closest zip codes. However, I can only seem to figure out how to select the single closest zip code. How can I adapt this for all zip codes:

```
SELECT
  zip, (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(78.3232) )
      * cos( radians( latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(65.3234) )
      + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
      * sin( radians( latitude ) )
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM zipcodes
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

This would select the 20 closes zip codes, but I would need to apply this to every row. How can I do this for the entire table at once?

Comment: Is that SQL correct? is there a function called "distance"? you have zip, distance(formula) as distance. Maybe you just want formula as distance?

Comment: btw, it can be done, but it will be heavy in computation. maybe have a look at this post first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points

Comment: check out the second formula on [philcolbourn answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle) i think its more suitable for you.

Comment: @koriander What are you talking about? `distance` is an alias for everything that precedes it.

Comment: @Strawberry, now it is because it is corrected

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), I think you can use the Haversine formula to calculate the distance between two points, given the latitude and longitude of each one:

Here's an example:

```
select zc.*
     -- First, convert the latitude and longitude to radians:
     , @lat1 := radians(@latitude) as lat1_rad  
     , @lon1 := radians(@longitude) as lon1_rad
     , @lat2 := radians(zc.latitude) as lat2_rad
     , @lon2 := radians(zc.longitude) as lon2_rad
     -- Calculate the differences in latitude and longitude:
     , @delta_lat := @lat2 - @lat1 as delta_lat
     , @delta_lon := @lon2 - @lon1 as delta_lon
     -- The Haversine Formula:
     , @a := pow(sin(@delta_lat / 2), 2) + cos(@lat2) * cos(@lat1) * pow(sin(@delta_lon / 2), 2) as a
     , @c := 2 * atan2(sqrt(@a), sqrt(1 - @a)) as c
     , @d := @R * @c as d -- Distance (Km)
from 
    (select @R := 6371  -- The radius of the earth (Km)
          , @latitude := 65.3234    -- Latitude of the initial point
          , @longitude := -78.3232  -- Longitude of the initial point
    ) as init,
    zip_codes as zc
-- Add any WHERE conditions and/or ORDER
;
```

If you want to put this in a function:

```
delimiter $$
create function haversine_distance(latitude1 double, longitude1 double
                                 , latitude2 double, longitude2 double)
returns double
-- Input: Latitude and longitude of the points you want to calculate,
          given in degrees
begin
    declare lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 double;
    declare delta_lat, delta_lon double;
    declare a, c, d double;
    declare R double default 6371; -- The radius of the Earth
    -- Convert the inputs to radians
    set lat1 = radians(latitude1);
    set lon1 = radians(longitude1);
    set lat2 = radians(latitude2);
    set lon2 = radians(longitude2);
    -- Calculate the differences between latitudes and longitudes
    set delta_lat = lat2 - lat1;
    set delta_lon = lon2 - lon1;
    -- The Haversine formula
    set a = pow(sin(@delta_lat / 2), 2) +
            cos(lat2) * cos(lat1) * pow(sin(delta_lon / 2), 2);
    set c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - 1);
    set d = R * c;
    return d;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

And finally, you can use this function to calculate the distances between two points, and filter the nearest `n`. I'll use user variables to define the latitude and longitude of the origin point:

```
set @latitude1 = 65.3234, @longitude1 = -78.3232;
set @n = 5; -- The number of nearest points
select zc.*
     , haversine_distance(@latitude1, @longitude1, 
                          zc.latitude, zc.longitude) as distance_km
from zip_codes as zc
order by distance_km
limit @n;
```