# Why does my Hough circle detection in android not work?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I have this program, that is trying to find circles in image. I am trying for some time now, but achieved no result yet.

I was debugging the program and i found that the problem is in this line: 
**Mat mat = new Mat();**

When I run the program, it unfortunately stops. Does anyone know why and how I can fix it?

```
MainActivity.java

package com.examp.filewithpic;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.aaa);
   // Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.aaa);

    ImageView image1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    ImageView image2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    image1.setImageBitmap(image);
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    Toast.makeText(this,"height:"+h+" width:"+w,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    /**************/
    /* Mat mat = new Mat(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
            CvType.CV_8U);
   */
    Mat mat = new Mat();
    mat.create(new Size(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), CvType.CV_8U);

    Mat grayMat = new Mat();
    grayMat.create(new Size(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), CvType.CV_8U);

    Utils.bitmapToMat(image, mat,false);

    /* convert to grayscale */
    int colorChannels = (mat.channels() == 3) ? Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY
            : ((mat.channels() == 4) ? Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY : 1);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, grayMat, colorChannels);

    /* reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection */
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayMat, grayMat, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

    // accumulator value
    double dp = 1.2d;
    // minimum distance between the center coordinates of detected circles in pixels
    double minDist = 100;

    // min and max radii (set these values as you desire)
    int minRadius = 0, maxRadius = 12;
    // param1 = gradient value used to handle edge detection
    // param2 = Accumulator threshold value for the
    // cv2.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT method.
    // The smaller the threshold is, the more circles will be
    // detected (including false circles).
    // The larger the threshold is, the more circles will
    // potentially be returned.
    double param1 = 70, param2 = 72;

    /* create a Mat object to store the circles detected */
    Mat circles = new Mat(image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8U);

    /* find the circle in the image */
    Imgproc.HoughCircles(grayMat, circles,
            Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, minDist, param1,
            param2, minRadius, maxRadius);

    /* get the number of circles detected */
    int numberOfCircles = (circles.rows() == 0) ? 0 : circles.cols();

    /* draw the circles found on the image */
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfCircles; i++) {


    /* get the circle details, circleCoordinates[0, 1, 2] = (x,y,r)
     * (x,y) are the coordinates of the circle's center
     */
        double[] circleCoordinates = circles.get(0, i);


        int x = (int) circleCoordinates[0], y = (int) circleCoordinates[1];

        Point center = new Point(x, y);

        int radius = (int) circleCoordinates[2];

        /* circle's outline */
        Core.circle(mat, center, radius, new Scalar(0,
                255, 125), 4);

        /* circle's center outline */
        Core.rectangle(mat, new Point(x - 5, y - 5),
                new Point(x + 5, y + 5),
                new Scalar(0, 128, 255), -1);
    }

    /* convert back to bitmap */
    Utils.matToBitmap(mat, image,false);


   }
  }
```

XML file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.examp.filewithpic.MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="58dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Log

```
enter code here
06-15 00:11:51.940: D/dalvikvm(1605): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 75K, 27% free  2728K/3728K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
06-15 00:11:51.940: I/dalvikvm-heap(1605): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.660MB for 1012012-byte allocation
06-15 00:11:51.950: D/dalvikvm(1605): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 22% free 3716K/4720K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
06-15 00:11:51.970: W/dalvikvm(1605): No implementation found for native Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;.n_Mat:()J
06-15 00:11:51.970: D/AndroidRuntime(1605): Shutting down VM
06-15 00:11:51.970: W/dalvikvm(1605): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95df5b20)
06-15 00:11:51.970: I/Process(1605): Sending signal. PID: 1605 SIG: 9
06-15 00:11:51.970: D/AndroidRuntime(1605): procName from cmdline: com.example.vvvv
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.vvvv
06-15 00:11:51.970: D/AndroidRuntime(1605): file written successfully with content: com.example.vvvv StringBuffer : ;com.example.vvvv
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605): Process: com.example.vvvv, PID: 1605
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:447)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at com.example.vvvv.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18433)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
06-15 00:11:51.970: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equation for testing if a point is inside a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle)

Comment: This question has been asked over and over. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle shows you the basic idea on how to do this.

Comment: He isn't asking for an algorithm to detect if a point is in a circle but why his implementation of an algorithm to detect circles in an image isn't working. In horrible english though.

Comment: Does the program throw any error when it does stop?