# How to get latlangs from the arraylist which are near to my current location?

Tags: android

I am having list of Latitude and logitudes. Entire latlang is available in the ArrayList.  How to get latlangs from the arraylist which are near to my current location ?

My current location latlang is - 40.711991 , -73.978543

For Example, below Given the entire latlangs, which is available in the ArrayList.

From my location, Around 100 meter, following latlangs are available.
40.709636 , -73.984766
40.717521 , -73.980775
40.718757 , -73.986268
40.717976 , -73.995795
40.716025 , -74.000602
40.7304 , -73.978286
40.729034 , -73.982835
40.730856 , -73.992105
40.709128 , -74.004378
40.709844 ,-73.987985

Following latlangs are out of 100 meter.
40.715504 , -73.922238
40.709193 , -73.901296
40.714203 , -73.868251
40.683879 , -73.875203
40.660704 , -73.8831
40.654454 , -73.896403

I need to show latlangs from the ArrayList which are close to my current location around 100 meter only. Out of 100 meter, I should not show.  How to do that ?  Kindly please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This has been asked a hundred times. Just google for it.

Comment: Use the Pythagorean theorem as your guide, and for a general primer on how to do this, check out this post.    

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle

Comment: Please provide the link for any implementation for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

You have to get lat and long one by one from arrayList and then

```
 //============= for current location ===========
 Location currLoc= new Location("");
 currLoc.setLatitude(currLocLat);
 currLoc.setLongitude(currLocLong);
```

Do iteration over arraylist, fetch one by one lat and longs and then,

```
  //============= for arrayList location ===========
  Location arrListLoc= new Location("");
  arrListLoc.setLatitude(arrLisLat1);
  arrListLoc.setLongitude(arrLisLong1);
```

You will get distance in meter by following method..

```
  float distanceInMeters = currLoc.distanceTo(arrListLoc);
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I ll try this.