# C# Console app How to check requested point is inside the main point(-3,4) with radius 10

Tags: c#, points

I am making a program, which checks if a user's requested point is inside the radius(10) of main point(-3,4). I don't know how to check it. Please help me!

For Example: User needs to know -5,3 is inside the main point (-3,4)

```
int radius = 10; //Radius

new Point(-5,3); //User's point

new Point(-3,4); //Main point
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equation for testing if a point is inside a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the distance between the 2 points using the below formula

```
Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((x2-x1),2)+Math.Pow((y2-y1),2))
```

if the value is less than the radius . then the Point lies inside the circle .

Comment: It's works too. Which better this or Coskun Ozogul solution?

Comment: @GyulaNemeth This solution works for all the cases .